# Number of integer triangles.

Tags: combinatorics

> Number of integer isosceles or equilateral triangle none of whose
>   sides exceed $2c$ is?

I substituted $c =3$ checked, and got $27= 3 \times (3^2)$ i.e. $3c^2$ triplets. It gives the right answer($3c^2$) but how do I write a proper formal proof of this?

I tried it this way: We have three vacant places for three integers. First place can be filled in $2c$ ways, 2nd one in $2c$ ways, 3rd one in $2c$ way but it involves over-counting, is it possible to eliminate the extras?

Comment: Not following.  With $c=3$, $36\neq 3c^2$.  Also, your method appears to ignore the triangle inequality (and it ignores the condition that the triangle be isosceles or equilateral).

Comment: $\text{card}(\{(a,b) \in ([0,2c]\cap \mathbb N)^2 \text{ | } 2a\geq b \})$

Comment: Because the triangles are isoceles you two slots will be the same.  So you only need two slots.  The third slot must follow the triangle inequality that $slot_3 < slot_1 + slot_1$.  So although slot 1 may be filled any $1 \le n \le 2c$ ways the third slot can only be filled in at most $2n-1$ ways (if $2n-1 < 2c$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define an isoceles triangle by an ordered pair $(b,n)$ where $b$ is the length of the base side and $n$ is the length of the two congruent sides.

The basic criteria are (basically the triangle inequalities)

i) $b > 0; n > 0$

ii) $b < 2n$

iii) (trivial and dumb) $n < b + n$ (which... well, duh....)

Any such pair is possible.

So with the additional requirement that $b \le 2c$ and $n \le 2c$, and $n,b \in \mathbb Z$ how many such ordered pairs may there be?

Well, our conditions are now:

i') $1 \le b\le 2c; 1\le n \le 2c$

ii') $b\le 2n-1$

iv) $n,b, c \in \mathbb Z$.

or in other words $1\le n \le 2c; 1 \le b \le \min(2n-1, 2c)$.

And *ANY* such pair of natural numbers will do.

So there are $\sum_{n=1}^{2c}(\sum_{b=1}^{\min(2c,2n-1)
} 1)=\sum_{n=1}^{2c} \min(2c,2n-1)$ such triangles.

$\sum_{n=1}^{2c} \min(2c,2n-1)=\sum_{n=1}^{c} \min(2c,2n-1))+ \sum_{n=c+1}^{2c} \min(2c,2n-1)$

$=\sum_{n=1}^{c}(2n-1)+ \sum_{n=c+1}^{2c}2c$

$= [2(\sum_{n=1}^cn)- c]+[c*2c]$

$= 2\frac {c(c+1)}2 - c + 2c^2$

$= 3c^2$

Comment: I didn't understand the two summations you've used

Comment: Which two? And why not.  It's just counting.  "counting to $7$ " can be represented as $\sum_{k=1}^7 1$.

Comment: Thanks! It's awesome. What if maximum limit was odd?

Comment: You'd do it the same way. $\sum_{n=1}^{2c-1} \min(2c-1,2n-1) = \sum_{n=1}^c 2n-1 + \sum_{n=c+1}^{2c-1}(2c-1) = c^2 + (c-1)(2c-1) = 3c^2-3c + 1$.  I think.  So if $c = 3$ and no sides can exceed $2*3-1 = 5$ we should have $19$ options.  $(1,1,1):(2,2,1)(2,2,2)(2,2,3):(3,3,1)(3,3,2)(3,3,3)(3,3,4)(3,3,5):(4,4,1)(4,4,2)(4,4,3)(4,4,4)(4,45) etc.$ seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b$ be the length of the base and $a$ be the length of the legs of such a triangle. Given $c\geq1$ we want
$$1\leq b\leq 2c, \quad {b\over2}<a\leq 2c\ .\tag{1}$$
If $b=2k-1$ with $1\leq k\leq c$ is odd the condition $(1)$ enforces $k\leq a\leq 2c$ and allows of $2c-(k-1)$ different integer values for $a$.

If $b=2k$ with $1\leq k\leq c$ is even then $(1)$ enforces $k+1\leq a\leq 2c$ and allows of $2c-k$ different integer values for $a$.

The total number $N$ of isosceles triangles having sides $\leq2c$ therefore is given by
$$N=\sum_{k=1}^c\bigl(2c-(k-1)\bigr)+\sum_{k=1}^c(2c-k)=4c^2-\sum_{k=1}^c(2k-1)=3c^2\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a recursive approach would work well.

The number of isoceles triangles with the two equal legs **equal** to $2c$, and the other shorter, is of course $2c{-}1$.

The number of isoceles triangles with the two equal legs equal to $2c{-}1$, and the other shorter, is $2c{-}2$.

The isosceles triangles with "base" of $2c$ and equal legs shorter is $c{-}1$, since the equal legs must be more than $c$ in length, and likewise with a base of $2c-1$ the count is also $c{-}1$ (since equal legs of $c$ will now qualify).

Adding the two equilateral triangles of sides $2c$ and $2c-1$, we get $3c{-}1$ triangles on the increment between $c{-}1$ and $c$.

So our cumulative value $t(c) = t(c-1) + 6c-3$, with $t(0)=0$ of course. Then the values $3,12,27,48,75,\ldots$ can be assessed to give $t(c) = 3c^2$.

Comment: But we need to reach $3c^2$

Comment: No, You need to reach the right answer.  If $3c^2$ is the right answer you need to reach it.  If $\frac {3c^2 +c}2 -1$ is the right answer you need to reach that.  Now, your complaint should be "but the book has a different answer".  (And according to my calculations the book is right.  But You are always on a losing battle if you struggle toward find the answer becuase it is what you are *supposed* to get.)

Comment: Joffran.  You didn't seem to take into account the isosceles triangles where the base is *longer* than the equal side.  So far as I can read there is no stipulation that the base is at most the length of the equal side. (which would make a fair and slightly harder question).

Comment: So for c=2 there are $(2,2,3),(3,3,4)(3,3,5),(4,4,5)(4,4,6)(5,5,6)$ triangles you did not consider for a total of $12 = 3*2^2$.

Comment: Hmmm,  Joffan seems to have interpreted this problem as requiring at least one leg of length $2c$ and none more than $2c$ in length.  I can not read anything in it that requires that one of the legs must be $2c$ in length.

Comment: @fleablood I'm looking at the limit case, where one side is equal to $2c$, and then translating from sequence to series. But I neglected to consider the $2c{-}1$ cases, which are also needed. Updating...

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you are doing it right.  It's just that my reading of the problem is that it didn't ask for the limit cases but all cases.

Comment: Right. And I accumulate those.